# delete query in JPA2 with related entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to do a bulk delete

```
@NamedQuery(name=CalcData.DELETE, 
query="delete from CalcData as model where model.dataLocation.locCountries = :locCountries and model.locPeriod= :locPeriod")
```

The prbolem is that hibernate translates this to

```
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    smart_rise.Calc_Data cross 
join
    smart_rise.Data_Location datalocati1_ 
where
    CountryID=? 
    and Period=?
```

This causes an exception when executin the namedquery

```
=== 2011-08-04 10:53:30,719 [l0-6] ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cross join smart_rise.Data_Location datalocati1_ where CountryID=6 and Period=10' at line 1
=== 2011-08-04 10:53:30,719 [l0-6] ERROR PeriodsDMI - org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute update query
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute update query
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
```

Any idea what went wrong?

thank you,
Zdary

Answer (score 3):

You cannot delete with a join.

If `locCountries` is an indexed collection Try subquerying:

```
delete from CalcData as model 
where :locCountries in indicies(model.dataLocation.locCountries)
and model.locPeriod= :locPeriod
```

If not:

```
delete from CalcData as model 
where model.id not in (select id from CalcData as m where model.dataLocation.locCountries = :locCountries  and model.locPeriod= :locPeriod
)
```

Regards.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a quick answer. I used
`Hibernate: 
  delete from smart_rise.Calc_Data 
  where ID in (select calcdata1_.ID 
    from
      smart_rise.Calc_Data calcdata1_ cross 
    join
      smart_rise.Data_Location datalocati2_ 
    where
      smart_rise.Calc_Data.LocationID=datalocati2_.ID 
      and datalocati2_.CountryID=? 
      and smart_rise.Calc_Data.Period=?
)`
I ended up with exception
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'Calc_Data' for update in FROM clause
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
`

Comment: This doesn't work in MySQL because it doesn't allow you to delete from an entity that you use in the select clause

Comment: To me, if it's still present in Hibernate, it's a bug, even if partly documented (for HQL though). Spec doesn't give any provision for this because it just should work, as described in JPA spec 2.1 §4.10 describing bulk updates, this paragraph referring where_clause described in §4.5.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? I'm confused on why the `-1`